# Python - Data Masking - Faker - fake.name error

Tags: python, masking, faker, data-masking

I'm trying to use Python faker and fake-factory for Data masking in my application. I have executed the following test python script but getting syntax error. Please help me out.

```
#faker script files
# coding=utf-8

from faker import Factory
fake=Factory.create()

fake.name()
fake.address()
fake.text()

for _ in range(0,10):
    print fake.name()
```

Error message:invalid syntax on **fake**

Comment: do you installed faker ??? pip install faker

Comment: Hello Roberto, I have installed faker in my local. Please check the log for the installation. I have used pip.

Comment: What version of python you use??? in python 2.7.x it's works perfectly

Comment: I m using 3.5.2 version. I'm totally new to faker and not sure what else I need to make this work.

Comment: What's the name of file? it's call "fake.py" ??

Comment: are you talking about the installation package file.? if so, here it is. AppData\Local\Programs\Python\faker\fake-factory-0.7.2\faker\factory.py

Comment: No, the name of script file and the directory ubication

Comment: Path : \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\faker\fake-factory-0.7.2\faker\tests and fakenametest.py is the file

Comment: do you create the directory "faker\test" ? move the file the another directory

Comment: the dir faker/test was already there. I just created the scripts under that folder. Now I moved them to desktop.

Comment: and now? show the same error ?

Comment: Yes. It's the same error again. I will clean up the faker folder and reinstall again.

Comment: Reinstalled the faker component again in python. Here is the folder : AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages\faker and tried again. But still facing the same error.

Comment: i have checked in the GitHub (https://github.com/joke2k/faker) and I tried to run the dependencies but the following file is not available at faker. Is that a problem? Here is the command  used `code` $ pip install -r faker/tests/requirements.txt `code`

Comment: Hello Rob, I just installed python 2.7 and it worked fine. There seems to be an issue with Faker - python 3.5. Thanks for your help anyway. I have got someone from twitter who used Faker and she suggested me to use Python 2.7. Unfortunately I do not know why it dint work with Python 3.5.  I will give an update as soon as I get the answer..

Comment: Excelent saran,

Answer (score 0):

You are using the print syntax incorrectly. The reason this worked on 2.x and not 3.x is that the way print works changed across versions. The one of you currently have is the python 2.x method.

Try :

```
for _ in range(0,10):
    print (fake.name()) # Put the call in parentheses
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it again.